# Requirements for transit at Dubai

Tags: transit, dubai

I have an Emirates flight from Luanda to Dubai arriving at terminal 3 and then an onward flight to Delhi on Air India Express from terminal 2 at Dubai.
What do I need to do with my checked in bags? Do I have to collect them and check in again at Dubai? Also, do I require a transit visa at Dubai for changing terminals?

Comment: Did you book a single ticket or separately?

Comment: It's a duplicate as to the visa question, but it's not as to the luggage question.